# GeoDjango and limit with bounding box query?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geodjango, extents

Just some context first, I have a postgres database with PostGIS extension, running under a GeoDjango wrapper. I have a weird bug that hopefully someone can shed some light on.

I'm running a query like this

```
geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)
query = Venue.objects.filter(location__within=geom)
```

This works fine for most cases and is doing exactly what I want, except for in one specific situation where I get a result that looks like this

[image: example of query bug]

(for reference, the bbox param above is always defined by the SW and NE corners of the map which in this case are

```
sw_lat:50.98777649091917
sw_lng:-0.9302881336211613
ne_lat:52.15534947527341
ne_lng:0.06946772575383875
```

)

I've been trying to narrow down the problem, and I'm starting to think it might be something to do with crossing from negative to positive longitude, but I'm not sure. Or maybe it is something to do with indexing on the database level?

---

Here is the SQL that is generated:

```
SELECT * FROM "web_venue" WHERE ST_Within("web_venue"."location", ST_GeomFromEWKB('\001\003\000\000 \346\020\000\000\001\000\000\000\005\000\000\000(\366\304G\026|I@\000(\\\317C\266\362\277(\366\304G\026|I@\000@\341z\036\272\305\277y\006C\216\230\021J@\000@\341z\036\272\305\277y\006C\216\230\021J@\000(\\\317C\266\362\277(\366\304G\026|I@\000(\\\317C\266\362\277'::bytea)) LIMIT 50
```

(I took out all the explicit select statements and just put '*' for brevity.)

Comment: Is there a limit on the query? You might only be seeing the first 100 results?

Comment: Yes there is a limit on the query, set to 50 at the moment. But in all other queries, the results come back as a scattering of points, spread roughly evenly inside the bbox, not all in a line like this.

Comment: You are probably near a split in the index.

Comment: There is a way to get Geodjango to print out the actual raw query it is running, but I forget what this is. This might be useful?

Comment: Edited the original post with the SQL output.

Comment: Because of the limit 50, I would imagine. What happens,  if you sort by y coordinate, for example?

Comment: I agree, the effect you see is probably not a bug but a coincidental effect due to the limit. Your points may have been entered into the DB in that order, or as iant said, the location might be at a index split or so.

Comment: John, in response to your question, sorting by the y coordinate just stacks all the points to the bottom of the bounding box (as expected), so yes, I'm guessing that it is mostly due to limit, rather than a bug. I will try to find a smart (and efficient) way to sort the points so that this isn't so much of a problem. Thanks for all your help guys.